# How to compare user-entered ID against IDs stored in database in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form that allows a user to create a new vendor.  I want the user to enter an ID for the vendor into a textbox but I need to make sure that the ID isn't already taken before creating the vendor.  If the ID is taken, I want a message to appear telling the user that the ID is taken and disable the submit button until a valid ID is entered.

I have a function that pulls the vendor IDs from the database and checks the user-entered ID against a List of IDs already in the database.  It returns a Boolean based on whether or not the user-entered ID is taken.

The problem I'm having is that it will not allow me to call this function within my javascript.  When running the application, it tells me "JavaScript runtime error: 'IsIdTaken' is undefined".  How can I call the function from within my javascript?  Or how can I get the IDs from the database to check them against the ID the user has entered?

Below is my code:

```
@model EnterpriseServices.Vendor.Vendor

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Vendor";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@functions {
    public static bool IsIdTaken(string userEnteredId)
    {
        bool isTaken = false;
        List<string> IDs = new List<string>();
        var vendors = EnterpriseServices.Vendor.VendorUtility.GetVendorIDandName();

        foreach (var v in vendors)
        {
            IDs.Add(v.Id);
        }

        if(IDs.Contains(userEnteredId))
        {
            isTaken = true;
        }

        return isTaken;
    }
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Create Vendor</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Vendor ID: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "IdTextBox" } }) <label style="color:red" id="idTaken">This ID is already taken</label>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Name: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Notes: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Is Active: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#idTaken').hide()
        $('#IdTextBox').focusout(function () {
            var textboxId = $('#IdTextBox').val($(this).val())
            if (textboxId != null)
            {
                //Check to see if the Vendor ID entered by the user is already being used
                if (IsIdTaken(textboxId.toString()))
                {
                    $('#idTaken').show()
                    $('#submitButton').disabled()
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#idTaken').hide()
                    $('#submitButton').enabled()
                }
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Will have to make an ajax call, passing in the id and then doing a database call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor is run server-side, Javascript is run client-side. You can't call a Razor function in JavaScript, because by that point, the server isn't involved any more. You need to use AJAX to send a request, with the id, to some endpoint (controller action) in your application. Then, return from that endpoint a bit of JSON indicating whether the value is valid or not. You can then use JavaScript to show/hide an error message based on the returned JSON. You'll also want to throttle your AJAX so that you only send a request after a certain threshold of characters has been entered or the user completely moves out of the field.

Comment: Thank you Chris.  I've never used AJAX before but I will look into this now.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I was able to get this working using AJAX, like Chris suggested.  I will post the code below for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

I would put all the vendor IDs on your model, so you only call it once (if you really want them on client). I would define your IsIdTaken method as a javascript method.

Comment: A valid approach, but be advised that the data is stale at that point. If there's multiple users filling out this form at the same time, you can still have collisions. You can still have collisions checking the id via AJAX, but at least then, you narrow it down to only instances where people post the same form within seconds of each other.

Comment: Yes, you will have to check server side in either case, the potential is there. Decision to trade performance for shrinking that potential time.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working using AJAX, like Chris Pratt suggested.

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#idTaken').hide()
        $('#IdTextBox').focusout(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("CheckId", "VendorUI")'+ '?id=' + $('#IdTextBox').val(),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    if (String(data) == "true")
                    {
                        $('#idTaken').show()
                        $('#submitButton').hide()
                        $('#IdTextBox').focus()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#idTaken').hide()
                        $('#submitButton').show()
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('AJAX FAILED');
                }
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

My Controller:

```
public JsonResult CheckId(string id)
        {
            bool isTaken = false;
            List<string> IDs = new List<string>();
            IList<LightweightVendor> vendors = VendorUtility.GetVendorIDandName();

            foreach (var v in vendors)
            {
                IDs.Add(v.Id);
            }

                if (IDs.Contains(id))
            {
                isTaken = true;
            }

            return Json(isTaken);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you let the database decide the ID for the vendor? If you still want to make a call to the database you will need to use ajax queries, I think the @functions is only called when razor builds the page and will not work with javascript calls once the page is loaded. If you search for that on stackoverflow many examples before you have been posted.